# Arithmetic Calculations in PHP for other region

Tags: php, math

I am doing project for Brazil Country in PHP Language.

there comma (,) and decimal will be interchanged ,for example

```
 Type       India    Brazil
 Decimal     10.34    10,34
 Big Value   10,234   10.234
```

when i do add or multiply in php it works fine for India,but for brazil it won't change formats.

is there any class i need to call ? i am very fresh for this kind of project

The code i tired,

```
$number = "29346.99"; //value
echo "$" .number_format($number, 2, '.', ',');
function strtonumber( $str, $dec_point=null, $thousands_sep=null )
 {
    if( is_null($dec_point) || is_null($thousands_sep) ) {
        $locale = localeconv();
        if( is_null($dec_point) ) {
            $dec_point = $locale['decimal_point'];
        }
        if( is_null($thousands_sep) ) {
            $thousands_sep = $locale['thousands_sep'];
        }
    }
    $number = (float) str_replace($dec_point, '.', str_replace($thousands_sep, '', $str));
    if( $number == (int) $number ) {
        return (int) $number;
    } else {
        return $number;
    }
}
Output:$29,346.99
```

Comment: Make sure that values are decimal point when you're working with them internally, and storing them; and only ever use a decimal comma for display purposes

Comment: @MarkBaker , do i need to write 2 diff code for India and Brazil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use this to parse locale strings to number:

  http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php
- Then do your calculations.
- To get the result of your calculations back to a locale string use:

  http://php.net/number_format

There are other options to do this, too.

Comment: i have gone through the PHP Manual , my bas luck i am using PHP Version 5.1.2 , but numfmt_create will support PHP 5 >= 5.3.0,your advice

Comment: Maybe using `localeconv` will do the trick, as mentioned at [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php).

Comment: its not working , it separates the thousands value ,ex , 29346.99 to 29,346.99,any idea ?

Comment: I did not check, if you are using the helper functions correctly (syntax of str_replace, etc.), but the idea for your strtonumber function seems good to me. But you haven't posted source code where the function is actually called, that may be the only mistake..?